# Upgrading a cat5e installation to cat 7 - what do I need to consider?

Tags: home-networking

I have just moved to an apartment that has existing cable runs installed with cat 5e wires. But now I have a 10 Gbps fibre connection I want to upgrade the internal cabling.

There is a central termination point in a utility room. The utility room closet contains an 8 port patch panel, and a fibre termination point from the street. I have an internet subscription with a 10 Gbps connection. The ISP supply a router with a single 10 Gbps port. I have a main computer in the second bedroom. This bedroom has a termination point for the cat5e cables with two sockets.

I only really need 10Gbps to the main PC. All my other devices are either wireless or just 1gbps.

What do I need to consider if I want to upgrade one of the cat5e cables to cat 7? Can I use the existing patch panels? Can I use the existing cable in some way to pull the new cable through?

Another alternative is to somehow route a fibre cable to the second bedroom, mount the ISP router there, run a single cat 7 cable to the main PC, then use the in wall mounted cat 5e to connect the router to a switch in the utility room. How easy is it to run a fibre cable through the existing channel runs?

Additional Info:

My ISP box is a [salt fibre box](https://fiber.salt.ch/en/box-en). It has one RJ45 10gbps port, 4 RJ45 1gbps ports, 1 fibre connection.

I also note the ISP router is actually a decent piece of kit with better wifi performance than my old access points. The central termination point and existing cat 5e patch panel is in a technical box that sandwiches the equipment between two metal sheets. Its not good for wifi performance.

Comment: *What do I need to consider if I want to upgrade one of the cat5e cables to cat 7?* Yes. 10G cannot work on 5e, needed at least 6 (in that case - 50m max), optimal 7 (up to 100m). *Can I use the existing patch panels?* 90% for "it will work normally". *How easy is it to run a fibre cable through the existing channel runs?* It depends on whether there is space in the channel, and not too small turning radiuses. Physically.

Comment: If you can to build separate fiber cable from central termination point (CTP) to your PC I'd recommend to build this optic patch to your station. Then 10G switch connected to ISP remains on CTP, and your station connected to another 10G port via optic patch.

Comment: @Akina So, this would be the sequence? CTP > ISP router/modem > optical patch > station? What equipment would I need to achieve this? See the question for the current equip specs.

Comment: Oh... I thought the provider would supply a common switch with two or more 10GBase-X SFP+ ports and corresponding WDM modules... *ISP box is a salt fibre box. It has one RJ45 10gbps port, 4 RJ45 1gbps ports, 1 fibre connection.* Does it has two 10Gbit ports - one FC WDM and one cooper? If so the only option is to replace cat5e to cat7. `ISP -> 10G optic -> router -> 10G cooper -> PC`. And `router -> 1G cooper -> another nodes`.

Comment: @Akina yeah that is what I figured. Thanks for the clarification. Do you think that the existing patch panels are ok for cat 7 10 gbps speed?

Comment: Really I have never tested. But I think it will be ok. Especially when the line from patch-panel to your PC is not too long. Anycase you can always temporarily install separate single cat7 sockets on both ends of new cable (or ever connect this cable to router directly) until patch panel replace if something will be wrong.